# No input found for varchar

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form, nested-attributes

I am trying use nested models in my rails application but I have a little issue.

This is my view:

```
<%= simple_form_for @installation do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :x %><br>
    <%= f.input :x %>
  </div>

  <%= f.simple_fields_for :address do |u| %>
    <div class="field">
      <%= u.label :street_address %><br>
      <%= u.input_field :street_address %>
    </div>
  <% end %>

<% end %>
```

When I run, I receive this error `<%= u.input_field :street_address %>` -> "No input found for varchar", but when I change this peace of code to `<%= u.input_field :street_address, :as => :string %>` work. Why this happen?

Comment: what is the data type of `street_address` that you define in schema?

Comment: @Hieu Pham varchar(200)

Comment: A simple Google search returned this: https://github.com/rails-sqlserver/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter/issues/411

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The magic is `simple form` will automatic detect your data type and automatically pick a input control for it. For instance:

```
text => text_area
string => text field
boolean => checkbox
```

As the [document](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form#available-input-types-and-defaults-for-each-column-type) described, there is not data type of `varchar` that `simple form` can understand autotically, so you need to specify the input type manually!

So you can use `as: :string` or `as: :text` to make it work!

Comment: and if is a collection ? @Hieu Pham

Comment: You can use checkbox or select, if it is still not helpful you can write your custom input, the detail is at https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form#available-input-types-and-defaults-for-each-column-type